# Ruby Time.now and Other dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strftime

I need to get three dates in variables

Today Since Midnight which I have as

> t = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:01") # 2012-11-19 00:00:01

Yesterday Since Midnight (i.e. 00:00:00 to 23:59:59)

> y1 = 2012-11-18 00:00:01 
>   y2 = 2012-11-19 23:59:59

it is specifically the y1 & y2 variables I need to create as strings for use in a gem. being new to ruby I am a little confused as Time.yesterday doesn't seem to do what I need

**EDIT**

For this be sure to include

> require 'active_support/all'

and ensure the gem is bundled for your application.

Used:

```
@current   = (Time.now).beginning_of_day.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
@yesterday = (Time.now - 1.day).beginning_of_day.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
@everything = (Time.now - 2.day).end_of_day.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do,

```
 t=Time.now
 y1=t-1.day
 y2=t+1.day
```

Answer (score 2):

```
t = Time.now
t - 1.day # => yesterday
t + 1.day # => tomorrow
```

Comment: i get this error `<top (required)>': undefined method `-' for "2012-11-19":String (NoMethodError)

Comment: You have to add or subtract to the time object, now the string you get with strftime.

Answer (score 1):

convert t to date first,

```
t = t.to_date

t - 1.day # => yesterday
t + 1.day # => tomorrow
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running Rails there's help to get from [ActiveSupport](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html)

```
1.day.ago.midnight
Time.new.beginning_of_day
```

You should also consider not using `2012-11-19 00:00:01` or `2012-11-19 23:59:59`.
Instead you could use 00:00:00 and compare with >= or < depending on what you want to achieve. If you always round to seconds then `2012-11-19 00:00:00` to `2012-11-19 23:59:59` would work.